# Spring specification avoid unexpected CROSS JOIN

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, hibernate-criteria, criteria-api

I have 2 entities:

- 1 is the Org Structure (with a self-join refers to its parent org structure)
- 2 is the Device (has FK from OrgStructure)

```
public class OrgStructure{

   @Id
   private Long id;

   @ManyToOne
   private OrgStructure parentOrgStructure;

}
```

```
public class Device {

   @Id
   private Long id;

   @ManyToOne
   private OrgStructure hospitalRoom
}
```

I have 1 specification which generates a CROSS JOIN query. My question is how to avoid unnecessary CROSS JOIN like this

```
criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get(Device_.orgStructure).get(OrgStructure_.parentOrgStructure).get(OrganizationStructure_.id), *param goes here*)
```

```
The generated query:
SELECT
    *
FROM
    devices device0_
CROSS JOIN org_structures organizati1_
WHERE
    device0_.hospital_room_id = organizati1_.id_organization_structure
    AND organizati1_.organization_structure_id =?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please change :

```
root.get(Device_.orgStructure).get(OrgStructure_.parentOrgStructure)
```

to

```
root.join(Device_.orgStructure).join(OrgStructure_.parentOrgStructure)
```